# Static files movement from Application server- Configurations in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, struts2, static-content

I tried to move the static contents of my application from the application server.

So I defined a path and put them into it.

My `server.xml` of jBoss has

```
<Host>
<Context docBase="D:\UI" path="/ui"/>
</Host>
```

I have the static contents in this path.

In my JSP's to define the JS path,  I defined use static files movement

```
<script src="<s:url value="/UI/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"/>"></script>
```

But I am not able to access the JS from the folder path defined in `server.xml`.

I get the following error:

```
INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction recovery manager
19:00:54,142 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] 
Error installing to Start: name=WebServer state=Create
org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Context cannot appear in this position. Expected content of Host is unordered_sequence: Listener* Valve* Alias* Realm? attributes?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `url` tag you should use absolute path

```
<script src="<s:url value='/ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js' includeContext='false'/>"></script>
```

You should not add context path to the url manually, the `url` tag will add it automatically.

Comment: yeah the way you have given is when we refer the js in the same ear.But here, I am putting all my static contents i.e. js and css to another folder and defining the path in server.xml of jBoss.

Comment: Url tag is built by default to the same context, but I changed it.

Comment: When the server mapping for the folder is done, absolute url serves the purpose.